# trouble creating a method that takes as an input an array of integers and return the reverse array

Tags: arrays, methods, return, reverse

I need help writing this code so i can reverse the array of integers and return it? Can anyone help?

```
public class Quesitons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8};

        int[] a = reverseArray(numbers);
        System.out.println(a);

    }

    public static int[] reverseArray(int[] numbers) {

        int [] newArray= new int [numbers.length];
        int temp;
        int left = numbers[0];
        int right = numbers.length; 
        int  mid = left+right/2;
        for (int i=0; i<mid;i++){
            temp = left;
            left= right;
            right= temp;

            right= right -1;
            left= left+1;

            left= newArray[0];
            right=newArray.length-1;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help you to get help if you explain the specific language you're working in.

Comment: What exactly isn't working about the code you have above?

Comment: well when i compile it or run it , i dont get the numbers in reversed order im thinking it might be because im not saving the numbers in a new array ?

Answer (score 0):

As with most tasks in programming, the easiest way to do this would be to not do much of any work at all. While there's no `reverse` method for arrays, there's a reverse method in `Collections`. So, if you were to use a `List` instead of an array, you could just call `yourList.reverse()`, and all the work will be done for you.

If you want or need to use an array, here's a method that'll return the reverse of an `int[]` passed to it:

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] input)
{
    int[] reversedArray = new int[input.length];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversedArray[j] = input[i];
        j++;
    }

   return reversedArray;
}
```

To summarize what this does: First, it creates a new array of the same length of the input array. Then, within a for loop moving from the last element of the input array to the first, it assigns each of those elements to the indices of the new array from the first to the last. So the last index of the input array gets assigned to the first index of the new array, and the second-to-last element to the second index, and etc.

Comment: well it works but when i run it i get this [I@15db9742

Comment: @Dee You're running this in ideone, aren't you? If you print each element of the array, you'll find that the result is what you want it to be. Ideone doesn't appear to support printing arrays.

Comment: im runnning it on netbeans and i dont know why its doing that hah ? its weird

Comment: @Dee I can basically guarantee the reason it's happening is because you're just calling `System.out.println($your_array$)`. Try iterating through the result of `reverseArray` like so: `for (int q : reverseArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) { System.out.println(q); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] numbers) {

    int[] newArray= new int[numbers.length];
    int counter = 0 ;
    for(int i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newArray[counter] = numbers[i];
        counter++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

call like this to see the result:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8};
int[] a = reverseArray(numbers);
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   Console.write(a[i]);
```

I have not tested it, but sure it should work.

Comment: right i mean it works but when it run it i get this [I@15db9742 ? can you explain why i get that ? please

Comment: can you post your called parameter values, and where you see that value?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different `for` loop to reverse the array:

```
for (int i = numbers.length -1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
{
   newArray[i] = numbers[j];
}
```

In a `for` loop, you can declare multiple, comma-separated variables. The only thing is that you can have only one escape clause (i.e. `i >= 0` or `j < array.length`)

Basically what you are doing is counting down on the reversed array while counting up on the original one.  Fairly simple implementation if you think about it.